# How to clone source from Launchpad?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, git, launchpad, development

I would like to recompile the kernel for Ubuntu touch tablet (bq m10), but can't clone the kernel source which is at launchpad [here](https://git.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/avila/+git/kernel-3.10).

I do on my machine `git clone <any git link from the site under clone section>`

git fetches source (i see one big pack file of ~700MB under .git/./..), but fails to extract the source. It throws a warning: `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout`

How to get the source? (do not offer the one on github by bq, but this one, as this one, in the launchpad, have backports and bluetooth stack with bluez applied; one in the github of bq origin is pure android and does not have bluez)

Comment: What is the output of `git branch`? The link you provided in the question is invalid, please double check it.

Comment: Just do `git checkout ubuntu`. An explanation of what is happening can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893678/warning-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout.

Comment: @edwinksl, could you add this as the answer, I will edit the questionto be more generic. thanks for the answer. that is not obvious, and is nowhere writen

Comment: should I delete this question?

Comment: @sem-geologist Oops, sorry, I was busy. I can write an answer now if you think that is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `git clone -b ubuntu`, or run `git checkout ubuntu` after cloning.

However, I've just set that repository's default branch to `ubuntu` in Launchpad, so `git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/avila/+git/kernel-3.10` etc. should work now without needing to manually choose a branch.